# How to access JSX component method in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, filepond

I'm using FilePond with react-final-form. I don't know how to access the methods of the FilePond adapter. FilePond has a [getFiles](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-instance/#methods) method I am trying to access.

```
const FileAdapter = ({ input: {value, onChange, ...rest}, pond}) => (
  <FilePond
    ref={pond}
    onprocessfiles={console.log(pond.getFiles())}
    />
)


class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.pond = React.createRef();
  }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <Form
              render={) => (
                <form>
                    <Field name="files" pond={this.pond} component={FileAdapter} />
                </form>
              )}
            />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following every time:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFiles' of undefined

Comment: Filepond has doc related to React (https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/frameworks/react/) It suggests define ref with `<FilePond ref={ref => this.pond = ref}/>` and then use `this.pond.getFiles();` This can be issue

Comment: @Fyodor Isn't that method deprecated in React?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` and `current`, see https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs

```
<FilePond
    ref={ this.pond }
    onprocessfiles={ () => console.log( this.pond.current.getFiles() ) }
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onprocessfiles` should be a callback.

```
onprocessfiles={() => console.log(pond.getFiles())}
```

As it is, you're calling `pond.getFiles()` on the first render and the ref hasn't been populated yet.